# Calculating average for two variables

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like follows:

```
VisitorID   Product         VisitDayBeforePurchase
1           Product1            0
2           Product2            1
3           Product3            2
1           Product1            2
3           Product2            2
3           Product3            2
```

VisitorID is always unique to each visitor, and visitDayBeforePurchase represents if they came to the website x days before a purchase.  What I'd like to do is craft a statement that can transform the table into something like this.

```
 Product   Day0   Day1  Day2
 Product1   1      0     1
 Product2   0      1     2
 Product3   0      0     2
```

Essentially, I want to see an average number of visits somebody visits the website X days before a purchasing a specific product. i.e. sum(visits)/sum(uniqueVisitors) per product per days before visit

I was just going to download data from table 1 and write a script to calculate this, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in SQL.

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Is there a max amount of days before they buy it? like 0, 1 and 2 or it could be indefinite number of days added to the right side as a new column?

Comment: I'd say 30 days max..and I'm using Teradata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a known number of columns the table you describe - which is not actually an *average*, it is a *count* - can be done using `IF`:

```
SELECT Product,
       SUM(IF(VisitDayBeforePurchase = 0, 1, 0)) AS Day0,
       SUM(IF(VisitDayBeforePurchase = 1, 1, 0)) AS Day1,
       SUM(IF(VisitDayBeforePurchase = 2, 1, 0)) AS Day2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Product;
```

> Essentially, I want to see an average number of visits somebody visits the website X days before a purchasing a specific product. i.e. sum(visits)/sum(uniqueVisitors) per product per days before visit

This is a different request. You can do this by adding (or replacing) a column

```
SELECT Product,
       AVG(VisitDayBeforePurchase) AS AverageDays
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Product;
```

This gives you all (you can see it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51904f/1/0)).

```
SELECT Product,
       SUM(IF(VisitDayBeforePurchase = 0, 1, 0)) AS Day0,
       SUM(IF(VisitDayBeforePurchase = 1, 1, 0)) AS Day1,
       SUM(IF(VisitDayBeforePurchase = 2, 1, 0)) AS Day2,
       AVG(VisitDayBeforePurchase) AS AverageDays
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Product;
```

## Accounting for multiple visitors

In a nutshell: *it's complicated, and maybe it's best not done at all*.

Say we have a product that gets viewed *twice* (or more) by the same visitor, then we do not want to count these as separate visits. If mr. X visited the site three days, two days, and on the day of purchase, what do we do?

At first sight we might think to only count the *last* visit. But we would get an obvious unintended consequence: since you have to visit the site to purchase an item on the site, then the *last* visit before the purchase is *the visit whereby you made the purchase*, and so it will always be zero days before the purchase itself. In the same hour and minute, even, possibly. While it is possible to consider the last visit, it would give us worthless results.

Considering the *first* visit also has the unintended consequence of overlooking repeated purchases, so that our *best* repeated customers will actually be considered as being the most diddling and indecisive.

So one would have to consider, for instance, only the day intervals actually tabulated with SUM, and *then* do something:

```
VisitorID       ProductID       VDBeforeP
42              137             3
42              137             2
41              137             2
```

But *what* to do? If we consider only *one* record for visitor 42, *whatever we do* we end up with an incorrect result, either too optimistic on average, or too pessimistic on average. We can consider user 42's *average*, which gives 2.5 for user 42 with weight *one* (instead of *two*), so in comparison with the "brute average" (solution above) we sort of consider repeated customers a bit less.

To do so, we use a `SUBSELECT`: we obtain the averaged data with only one Visitor and Product for each data point

```
SELECT VisitorID, Product, AVG(VisitDayBeforePurchase) AS VisitDayBeforePurchase
    FROM visits GROUP BY VisitorID, Product;
```

and this will yield a table with the same format as the original one, but with averaged data. **And it will never work** because the original query only verified *integer* numbers of days, and 2.5 is neither 2 nor 3. So we have to make either an optimistic or pessimistic correction; this is the optimistic

```
SELECT VisitorID, Product, FLOOR(AVG(VisitDayBeforePurchase)) AS VisitDayBeforePurchase
    FROM visits GROUP BY VisitorID, Product;
```

while the pessimistic would use `FLOOR(1.0+AVG...`. A compromise would be to use `ROUND`.

Now we repeat the query:

```
SELECT Product,
    SUM(IF(V = 0, 1, 0)) AS Day0,
    SUM(IF(V = 1, 1, 0)) AS Day1,
    SUM(IF(V = 2, 1, 0)) AS Day2,
    AVG(BetterV) AS AverageDays
FROM (
    SELECT VisitorID,
           Product,
           ROUND(AVG(VisitDayBeforePurchase)) AS V,
           AVG(VisitDayBeforePurchase) AS BetterV
    FROM visits GROUP BY VisitorID, Product
) AS grouped
  GROUP BY Product;
```

**[A working example can be also found here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51904f/6/0)**

## Map-Reduce

To run the above in a map-reduce environment you would need two stages: a map stage to directly output VisitorID, Product and VisitDayBeforePurchase, and a reduce stage to group by key (VisitorID, Product) and output those and the V (and BetterV?) calculation results.

This gets fed to a new reduce stage that performs averages on the V's.

Comment: I tried to modify the statement to `SUM(IF(VisitDayBeforePurchase = 0, 1, 0)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(VisitorID)) AS Day0,` in order to get the average, but got an error

Comment: So, I'm looking to divide the SUM of VisitDayBeforePurchase by the COUNT(DISTINCT(VistorID)) for each day.  That way I can see the average amount of views a product gets x days before purchase.

Comment: I can't say I've understood what you're trying to achieve. I'm trying to amend the answer to take into account the distinct visitorship thing, but this approach has issues.

Comment: There's no IF in Standard SQL/Teradata, you should use SUM(CASE WHEN VisitDayBeforePurchase = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Iserni.  The idea behind the query is to examine the purchasing funnel for each product.  For for example, the report may show that visitors start researching product1 two weeks in advanced of a purchase, while product2 is only viewed the same day as the purchase.  So, essentially for each product, I want to look at the last 30 days and see if there are any interesting browsing/research patterns - this information could be used to help with marketing efforts.